# Codeigniter controller didn't load view as well error message

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I was just making a simple room reservation system for my hotel using Codeigniter as framework. In my localhost the controller and its methods are working as expected, but when I upload the files to a testing server of mine, one of my controller became unaccessible. Neither it shows loaded view pages nor error. I've tried with url like www.mydomain.com/testing/index.php/room_booking and www.mydomain.com/testing/index.php/room_booking/post_action too but nothing is shown and then I've tried using die ('my code is not executed'), but it didn't print die either. So it made me go crazy and I elapsed my whole day.

**My Controller is as:**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class room_booking extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('dbmodel');
        $this->load->model('api_model');
        $this->load->model('dashboard_model');
        $this->load->model('booking_room');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library("pagination");
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('template/imageDiv');
        $this->load->view('template/reservation_template');
        //$this->load->view('login/test');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

    function post_action() {

        $this->load->helper('availableroom');
        die('here i used die function for test'); 
        if ($_POST) {

            $data['abc'] = array(
                'checkin' => $_POST['checkin'],
                'checkout' => $_POST['checkout'],
                'adult' => $_POST['adult'],
                'child' => $_POST['child'],
                'hotelId' => $_POST['hotelId'],
                'title' => $_POST['title']
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data['abc']);
            $hotel = $_POST['hotelId']; // form top it got hotel name       
            $hotels = $this->dashboard_model->get_hotel_id($hotel);
            if (!empty($hotels)) {
                foreach ($hotels as $hotelData) {
                    $hotelId = $hotelData->id;
                }
            } else {
                $hotelId = $_POST['hotelId'];
            }
            $data['query'] = $this->dashboard_model->booking_room($hotelId);
            $data['json'] = json_encode($data['query']);
            $this->load->view('ReservationInformation/room_booking', $data);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('ReservationInformation/room_booking_empty_view'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing any mistake here? In post_action method I passed a value from ajax call. How can I have it solved in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. I think you might forget to set your base url:

```
    // application/config/config.php
    $config['base_url'] = 'www.mydomain.com/testing';
```

It's just a guess (didn't post it as a comment because of privileges).

Comment: It is error 500 (Internal Server Error).
You can check out apache error logs for details or enable error reporting in php, to see the error message.

Comment: I'm not getting anything while tried from my location.......can you send me my errors @maicher

Answer (score 0):

Controller class name should start with `Uppercase letter`, so `room_booking` should be `Room_booking`

check note here: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#what

Comment: sorry for mistaken copy paste I'm using this as Room_booking in local and in server too